# What's wrong with this SQL query?

Tags: database, mysql, query

I have an SQL query which I'm adding to a small search plugin, however when I run the SQL in MySQL it works and results are found, however no rows are being returned when running the code in the plugin. Any ideas?

```
$query = ee()->db->query('
    SELECT c.cat_url_title, c.cat_name, ch.channel_name FROM exp_categories c
    LEFT JOIN exp_channels ch ON ch.cat_group = c.group_id
    WHERE c.cat_name LIKE "%' . ee()->db->escape_str($keywords) . '%"
');
```

UPDATE (moved from further answer)
Thanks. I was being thick! the query was working correctly. I was sending it the wrong parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran it and I'm getting results just fine.

Are you outputting the results correctly?

```
$query = ee()->db->query('SELECT cat_url_title, cat_name, ch.channel_name  FROM exp_categories c
        LEFT JOIN exp_channels ch ON ch.cat_group = c.group_id
        WHERE c.cat_name LIKE "%'.ee()->db->escape_str($keywords).'%"');
foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    echo $row['cat_name']."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I was being thick! the query was working correctly. I was sending it the wrong parameter